# Render button using if else reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was playing around with React js today and got stuck at one point. Basically, I want to render a button based on an if-else operator. However, while the first part (displaying "Error") is working when the value becomes equal to zero, the second part (rendering button) is not.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Items extends Component {
    
    state = { 
count: 0

     }
    
addItem=()=>
{
    this.setState({addition: this.state.count++})
    
}
removeItem=()=>
{
 let error;
    if(this.state.count===0)
    {
        this.setState({param: this.state.count="Error "});
       error= <button>Ooops <button>
        
        
        
    }
    else
    {
        this.setState({subtraction: this.state.count--})

    }
        }
    
       
                
  
    

    render() { 
        return ( 
            
<div>

<text>
Current count: {this.state.count}

</text>
<button onClick={this.addItem}>Increment</button>
<button onClick={this.removeItem}>Decrement</button>
<h3>{this.state.count}</h3>








</div>



         );
    }
}
 
export default Items;
```

I know that this question may sound dumb, but any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Can you format your code first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Items extends Component {

  state = {
    count: 0
  }

  addItem = () => {
    // ++ operator mutates the state object which should not be used!
    // The key should be 'count' instead of 'addition'.
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }

  removeItem = () => {
    // -- operator mutates the state object which should not be used!
    // The key should be 'count' instead of 'addition'.
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 })
  }

  render() {
    // The error message can be conditionally rendered based on the state value inside the render function.
    // Remember to close the button tag, you forgot to use the leading slash.
    return (
      <div>

        <text>
          Current count: {this.state.count}
        </text>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={this.removeItem}>Decrement</button>
        <h3>{this.state.count}</h3>

        {this.state.count === 0 ? (<button>Ooops </button>) : ''}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

L’affichage conditionnel en React fonctionne de la même façon que les conditions en Javascript. On utilise l’instruction Javascript if ou l’opérateur ternaire pour créer des éléments représentant l’état courant, et on laisse React mettre à jour l’interface utilisateur (UI) pour qu’elle corresponde.